# Почему в Search Console неадекватные показатели и как с этим бороться? Как получить адекватную статистику по переходам из гугла?

Tags: seo, google-analytics, google-search-console

[image: скриншот гугл серч консоли]
При сортировке по кликам, видно что за 3 месяца было всего 5 кликов суммарно. В то же время, по графику видно, что за последние 3 месяца кликов было явно больше чем 5 шт. От чего такая неточность и противоречие самой себе у Search Console? И как понять, по каким запросам и в каком количестве из гугла в действительности приходили люди?
По сводке из яндекс метрики, за последние 3 месяца на сайт пришло из поисковой системы Google 97 человек, но поисковые запросы гугла в яндекс метрике к сожалению не отображаются.. и в консоли некорректно отображаются - ну и как все таки статистику по переходам из гугла собирать...?

Comment: Все аналитические платформы не представляют точные данные, но только тренд. Для получения точной статистики используйте журналы сервера.

Comment: Подскажите пожалуйста, как с помощью журналов сервера собирать данные о  поисковых фразах, по которым на сайт приходят из гугла?

Comment: @nikant25 Есть информация, что в журналы сервера это не попадает. Раньше когда то попадала, а теперь уже нет - гугл решил что владельцам сайтов получать подобного рода данные подобным образом не стоит...

Comment: Такого не может быть. Владелец веб-сайта является также и владельцем журналов сервера для веб-сайта. Журналы сервера являются частью веб-сайта и, соответственно, являются личным объектом/имуществом владельца веб-сайта (до тех пор пока этот объект оплачен). Гугл не имеет права посягать на личное имущество и никогда не будет делать это. Гугл имеет другие приоритеты. Вас кто то либо вводит в заблуждение, либо обманывает.

Comment: @nikant25 может быть и вводят в заблуждение, но говорят что гугл технически пресек передачу ключевых слов при переходе по ссылкам из гугла, а на сами журналы он конечно не посягал. Могли бы вы подсказать, или дать наводку, как я смогу посмотреть журналы и убедиться в наличии/отсутствии ключевых слов, которые искали пользователи гугла и по которым перешли на мой сайт из гугла?

Comment: Ключевые слова представляют сущности содержания и для Гугл бессмысленно запрещать ключевые слова которые помогают Гугл в определении релевантного содержания. О проверке журналов сервера https://www.google.com/search?q=%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA+%D0%BF%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%BC%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%82%D1%8C+%D0%B6%D1%83%D1%80%D0%BD%D0%B0%D0%BB+%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B0

Comment: @nikant25 Смотрю логи /logs/2021-04/mysite.ru_access.log Хостинг jino. Ключевые слова из органического поиска как будут обозначены - как utm_term или как их найти? Вижу строки вида /?utm_source=google&utm_medium=cpc&... значит, на сколько понимаю, передача referer включена и cpc означает оплату за клик (рекламу), а из поиска без рекламы вместо cpc должно быть написано organic? Вот только нигде в логах этого слова нет, но то что приходят из поисковых систем - сомнений нет, потому что в гугл консоли они числятся.

Comment: @nikant25 http://blog.clickdimensions.com/google-ends-search-keywords-for-marketers/

Comment: Содержание вашего блога противоречит руководству Гугл для Дисковер https://support.google.com/websearch/answer/9982767. Ваша поисковая консоль показывает 5 кликов и столько же кликов показывает ваш второй скриншот. Субъект вашего блога есть обучение поисковой оптимизации и ваша проблема есть ординарная для эксперта поисковой оптимизации.

Comment: @nikant25 абзацу с каким заголовком из приведенного вами руководства  противоречит этот блог? В вопросе я публиковал лишь один скриншот и 5 кликов там только в одном месте показывает консоль - во втором месте она показывает 76 кликов, так что вы ошибаетесь, говоря что поисковая консоль на моих скриншотах показывает 5 кликов в обоих местах. Не будем про проблемы в контексте экспертов - эксперты утверждают что в логах сервера невозможно найти поисковые фразы, по которым из гугла пришли на сайт. По вашему, если в логах эти слова все же есть, то с пометкой "organic"?